# google analytics are killed after "cookie control" instalation

Tags: cookies

I'm new in drupal so I will write as simple as possible. I have installed the "google analytics" (GA) module. I have configured it and it worked. I was able to see live statistics on the GA web-page. Then I had quite stupid idea and I have installed "cookie control" (CC) module. After some time I have recognize that on the GA web-page I get no results... - no live-stats. So first I had disabled the CC module. But again there were no GA-live-stats :( so I have removed the CC module from the sites/all/modules, but that does not change anything. GA does not show any new stats since I have installed the CC module. How to proceed now?

Best regards,
kami

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much what [Cookie Control](https://drupal.org/project/cookiecontrol) is for.

> On May 26th 2011 a new EU originated law came into effect that requires website owners to make significant changes to their sites and may fundamentally change the whole web browsing and shopping experience for everybody.This Cookie Law is amended privacy legislation that requires websites to obtain informed consent from visitors before they can store or retrieve any information on a computer or any other web connected device.
>
> Cookie Control does just that, presenting users with clear information on whether cookies are present, linking to your privacy policy (where you should have specific information about what cookies are in use), and advising users on how to adjust browser settings and what cookies mean for them.
>
> ## Features
>
> - Compact pop-up with dark and light colour themes.
> - Prevent users logging in until cookie consented.
> - Other modules can integrate with cookie callbacks (see below).
> - Configurable message and read more message.
> - Link to an admin defined privacy policy node.
> - Only apply cookie consent restrictions to specified countries or whole world.
>
> ## 3rd Party Module Support
>
> A sub-module is bundled with Cookie Control which **will disable Google Analytics from tracking a visitor until they give consent.** Upon accepting cookies their first visit will be logged, along with any further page loads.

Emphasis mine.

So if you want to track people who do not consent for being tracked, you need to stop obeying the law - by disabling or modifying modules that makes your site law compliant.

## If you in fact disabled CC module

and GA is silent, then if you have no (or not much) new users, or you haven't cleared your caches, or ISP caches, then yes, it can last up to a week (usually a day or two). Try uninstalling this module, not only disabling, too. If it lasts longer than about a week, and GA can't even detect you when you browse from a browser you are sure never seen CC-enabled version on your site, then you are in trouble and it might be worth to compare your site (especially HTML, JS and headers output) with a backup from before first CC installation. But **it would be a bug in [Cookie Control](https://drupal.org/project/cookiecontrol)**, and you should report them in [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/cookiecontrol), not here.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Yes I understand what for is the CC module. BUT after removing it from "sites/all/modules" I see NO stats in the GA web-page. Is that normal?

Comment: @nykon answer updated.